# _TypeError was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>> type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am doing one flutter course while running the code I am getting `type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'`.

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import '../widgets/drawer.dart';
import 'package:glass_morphism/widgets/progress.dart';
import 'package:glass_morphism/widgets/message_bubble.dart';

late User loggedInUser;
final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChatScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ChatScreen> createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  final messageTextController = TextEditingController();
  late String messageText;
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  void initState() {
    getCurrentUser();
    super.initState();
  }

  void getCurrentUser() async {
    try {
      // ignore: await_only_futures
      final user = await _auth.currentUser!;
      // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
      if (user != null) {
        loggedInUser = user;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print(e);
    }
  }


  void messagesStream() async {
    await for (var snapshot in _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots()) {
      for (var message in snapshot.docs) {
        print(message.data().cast());
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent[100],
        elevation: 0,
        title: const Text('G R O U P  C H A T', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14),), centerTitle: true,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              messagesStream();
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.person, size: 24, color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      drawer: const DrawerWidget(),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children:  <Widget>[
            const MessagesStream(),
            Container(
              decoration:  BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(
                  top: BorderSide(color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent.shade100, width: 2.0),
                ),
              ),
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: messageTextController,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        messageText = value;
                      },
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                        hintText: 'Type your message here...',
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      messageTextController.clear();
                      _firestore.collection('messages').add({
                        'text': messageText,
                        'sender': loggedInUser.email,
                        "time": DateTime.now(),
                      });
                    },
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.send,
                      size: 24,
                      color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent[100],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class MessagesStream extends StatelessWidget {
  const MessagesStream({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _firestore.collection('messages').orderBy('time', descending: false).snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: circularProgress(),
          );
        }
        final messages = snapshot.data!.docs.reversed;
        List<MessageBubble> messageBubbles = [];
        for (var message in messages) {
          final messageText = message.get('text');
          final messageSender = message.get('sender');
          final messageTime = message.get('time') as Timestamp;
          final currentUser = loggedInUser.email;

          final messageBubble = MessageBubble(
            sender: messageSender,
            text: messageText,
            isMe: currentUser == messageSender,
            time: messageTime,
          );
          messageBubbles.add(messageBubble,
          );
        }
        return Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            reverse: true,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 20,),
            children: messageBubbles,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

`message_bubble.dart`:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// ignore: use_key_in_widget_constructors
class MessageBubble extends StatelessWidget {
  MessageBubble({required this.sender, required this.text, required this.isMe, required  this.time});

  final String sender;
  final String text;
  final bool isMe;
  late User loggedInUser;
  final Timestamp time;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: isMe ? CrossAxisAlignment.end : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(sender,
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 12,
              color: Colors.black54,
            ),
          ),
          Material(
            borderRadius: isMe ? const BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(30.0))
            : const BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                bottomRight:  Radius.circular(30.0),
              topRight:  Radius.circular(30.0),
            ),
            elevation: 4.0,
            color: isMe ? Colors.deepPurpleAccent[100] : Colors.white,
            child:  Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
              child: Text(
                text,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: isMe ? Colors.white : Colors.deepPurpleAccent[100],
                  fontSize: 15,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Error I am getting:

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _TypeError was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot<Object?>, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>>#c58b6):
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>> StreamBuilder:file:///C:/Users/prash/StudioProjects/glass_morphism/lib/main_screen/chat_screen.dart:128:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      MessagesStream.build.<anonymous closure> (package:glass_morphism/main_screen/chat_screen.dart:145:21)
#1      StreamBuilder.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:442:81)
#2      _StreamBuilderBaseState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:124:48)
#3      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4919:27)
#4      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4806:15)
#5      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#6      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#7      StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#8      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#9      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#10     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#11     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4883:5)
#12     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#13     RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5825:32)
#14     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6375:17)
#15     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#16     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#17     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#18     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
#19     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#20     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#21     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#22     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#23     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#24     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4883:5)
#25     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#26     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#27     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#28     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4883:5)
#29     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#30     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#31     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#32     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
#33     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#34     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#35     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#36     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
#37     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#38     RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5825:32)
#39     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6375:17)
#40     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#41     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#42     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#43     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#44     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#45     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#46     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#47     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#48     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
#49     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#50     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#51     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#52     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#53     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#54     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#55     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#56     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#57     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#58     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#59     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
#60     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#61     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#62     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#63     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#64     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#65     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#66     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#67     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#68     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#69     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#70     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#71     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#72     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#73     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#74     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#75     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
#76     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#77     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#78     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#79     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
#80     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#81     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#82     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#83     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#84     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#85     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#86     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#87     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#88     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
#89     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#90     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#91     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#92     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#93     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#94     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#95     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#96     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#97     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#98     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2659:19)
#99     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:891:21)
#100    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:370:5)
#101    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1146:15)
#102    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1083:9)
#103    SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:864:7)
(elided 4 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, and dart:async-patch)
====================================================================================================
Reloaded 2 of 968 libraries in 2,317ms.

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 99399 pixels on the bottom.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Column Column:file:///C:/Users/prash/StudioProjects/glass_morphism/lib/main_screen/chat_screen.dart:71:16
The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.

Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView.

The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#83981 relayoutBoundary=up2 OVERFLOWING
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=411.4, 0.0<=h<=651.4)
...  size: Size(411.4, 651.4)
...  direction: vertical
...  mainAxisAlignment: spaceBetween
...  mainAxisSize: max
...  crossAxisAlignment: stretch
...  verticalDirection: down
◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
====================================================================================================
```

I don't know how to resolve this error. I am not even sure what exactly this error is. Although I am searching and trying to figure it out. But those solutions didn't work for me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. All I did was **clean the database**. Here I was using Firebase, so I cleaned the database and after the hot restart, it started working.
The reason is Cleaning the database in Firebase can solve the null problem because it removes all the empty values and reduces the number of null references in your data. This can improve the performance and accuracy of your app, as well as reduce the risk of errors and crashes.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

here is your answer

```
final messageBubble = MessageBubble( text: messageText **?? ''**, sender: messageSender **?? ''**);
    messageBubbles.add(messageBubble);
```